# Triangle Mesh - Face отображаеться будучи прикрытым

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, mesh

Добрый день присутствует следующая проблема отображения модели - При условии что некоторая грань должна быть прорисована(вектор нормали направлен к камере) и не взирая на то что между указанной гранью и камерой присутствует другие грани(лицевая сторона модели) грань тыльной стороны все равно прорисовывается.Немного изображений для ясности:
(изометрия)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
(проблема)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Особенно эта проблема заметна при наложении света и материала
Ну и суть вопроса: как подобное решается в JavaFX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подробный ответ получен: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38554262/4817797)

Первопричина проблемы в соседствующих гранях с нормалями направленными во внутрь.